# Subsetting a data frame - Confused about syntax

Tags: r

Say I have the following data frame:

```
 LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1   6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2  10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3   9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4  11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
5   4.800   5   56.9    no   male        no
6   6.225  11   58.7    no female        no
```

Now I want to select all rows where the age is > 11 and gender is female. This gets me what I want:

```
y[y$Age>11&y$Gender=="female",]

  LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
2  10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3   9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
```

But this does not:

```
y[y$Age>11&y$Gender=="female"]

  Age Height
1   6   62.1
2  18   74.7
3  16   69.7
4  14   71.0
5   5   56.9
6  11   58.7
```

I'm very new at R and I don't understand what this second query is doing, other than it's not giving me what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subset the dataframe with the first syntax, the first number vector (or logic vector) in the square brackets represents the rows you want to select, while the second (after the comma) represents the columns.

If you do not explicitly insert anything after the comma, R assumes you want all the columns.

If you do not even put the comma, R assumes that the first number refers to what columns you want.

In your case `y$Age>11&y$Gender=="female"` is a logic vector that refers to position 2 and 3. So if you do not use comma, R thinks you want to only select columns 2 and 3. Therefore you get Age and Height.

Comment: Yep. It might also be worth mentioning this is because a `data.frame` is also a `list` containing each column. E.g. - `unclass(iris)` shows this underlying structure. So therefore selecting by `dat[n]` returns the `n`th vector (i.e column) in the list. Similarly, `dat[logical_vector]` returns the vectors in the list corresponding to `TRUE`.

Comment: You said that if I don't even enter a comma R assumes the first number refers to what columns I want. What number are you referring to? I didn't enter any numbers. I just entered what I wanted to search for.

Comment: @RandyMinder numeric or logical vector is what was intended.  Either works for indexing a data frame.

Comment: @RandyMinder Yeah I edited to correct that. Now the answer mentions number vector or logic vector. You can subset a dataframe using a vector that contains the position of what you want, or a logic vector that contains a series of TRUE and FALSE. In the second case only the elements corresponding to TRUE are selected. `y$Age>11&y$Gender=="female"` belongs to the second case.

Comment: @thepule - I don't follow you. How does the vector refer to position 2 and 3? Age is column 2 and Gender is column 5.

Comment: @RandyMinder If you execute `y$Age>11&y$Gender=="female"` you will get a vector like `c(FALSE, TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)` because rows 2 and 3 are the ones that satisfy your conditions. By not inserting the comma, R interprets it as a selection on the columns, therfore you get columns 2 and 3.

Comment: @thepule - You just repeated yourself. How does it refer to position 2 and 3?